# The sum of NaNs: How is the underlying bit pattern calculated?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, nan, ieee-754

**Question**: How does the JVM compute the sum of two double-precision NaNs?

Details: The IEEE 754 specification reserves two ranges of bit patterns for NaNs:

`0x7ff0000000000001 -> 0x7fffffffffffffff`

and

`0xfff0000000000001 -> 0xffffffffffffffff.`

IEEE 754 requires the sum of two NaNs to be a NaN, but, as far as I can tell, is silent on implementation details. So, to get to my question: If we write `b(x)` for the hexadecimal bit pattern of a NaN `x`, I'd like to know: How does the JVM calculate `b(x + y)` from `b(x)` and `b(y)?` Playing with a little bit of code, I'm lead to believe:

**Claim**: Let `t = 0x0008000000000000`. If `b(y) + t` is in a valid NaN range, then:

```
b(x + y) = b(y) + t
```

otherwise,

```
b(x + y) = b(y).
```

This seems strange to me, and I'd like to know more. For the record, I'm using Java 8 on an Intel i7 MacBook (in case the Java version or physical hardware matter.) Here are two examples:

Example 1, where `b(x + y) = b(y):`

```
b(x) = 0x7fffddee0f43e7d4
b(y) = 0xfffaeaba08397e4e
b(x + y) = 0xfffaeaba08397e4e
```

Example 2, where `b(x + y) = b(y) + t:`

```
b(x) = 0xffff4f0202031106
b(y) = 0xfff79342c97104ff
b(x + y) = 0xffff9342c97104ff
```

Does anyone know how the sum is being evaluated by the JVM?

Thanks!

Comment: The JVM doesn't do this: the hardware FPU does, and it does so in accordance with the IEEE-754 rules.

Comment: Note that the JVM **actually** uses the FPU and unless you use `strictfp` the FPU has **greater** precision than IEEE-754 (**unless** you run it on an IBM iSeries or Mainframe; that is a ***challenging*** "bug" to identify and correct).

Comment: Commonly, the high bit of the significand indicates whether a NaN is signaling (0) or quiet (1). A common behavior for handling NaNs is that, when an operation has NaN inputs and should produce a NaN output, one of the input NaNs is used (since this helps trace the history of a NaN found later in the program). Additionally, it is changed to a quiet NaN. This matches the results shown in the question: The bits come from one of the operands and the signaling/quiet bit is set.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, very helpful! @EricPostpischil your note about the significand was particularly illuminating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For floating-point, most implementations simply rely on what the underlying hardware does. Assuming you're running this on some sort of an x86 architecture, here're the rules: (You can find this in Section 4.8.3.5 of https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Wonderful answer! Thanks so much, @alias!